# Send or share DI data through network advice

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, network, data-acquisition

i want to collect some data(DIs from some relays) and send them or use them in a network and finally put them in a DataBase like SQL, and i want it to work 24/7.

after searching i found some solutions like using Raspberry pi with network socket . but i think its kind of too much for this work, also not sure if it can work 24/7.

if any one know any other modules or easier solutions that can do this , i would appreciate it to introduce.

i know there are Arduino modules too, but not sure how difficult it is to get data from it through TCP-IP network. or about working 24/7.

thanks in advance .

Comment: Raspberry Pi works fine 24/7, as does Arduinos. How difficult it is depends on your experience. The Pi has the advantage that it could talk directly to your database (or even house one on board). Arduinos have a cost/size advantage (although Ethernet shields take that away).

Comment: I have experience with AVR programming long time ago, now currently i am fine with python and java programming, and also working with databases.but not much with C.

Comment: Python and Java work on Raspberry Pi. "Wiring", the base of the language of Arduinos (but has libraries for Pi as well) is basically C wrappers. There are some embedded systems that run micro python, but I'm not sure of the project maturity.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work 24/7?